# Spinner wont show selected and wont respond to item selection

Tags: java, android, android-studio, drop-down-menu, spinner

I'm trying to make a very very simple spinner at least, as follows:

**XML:**

```
<Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spinner_categories"
     android:layout_width="0sp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>
```

**JAVA:**

```
spinnerCategories = findViewById(R.id.spinner_categories);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                categories);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerCategories.setAdapter(adapter);
Log.d(Utilities.LOG_FLAG, "SPINNER: " + spinnerCategories.toString());
spinnerCategories.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(context, categories.get(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(Utilities.LOG_FLAG, "SELECTED");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                Log.d(Utilities.LOG_FLAG, " NOT SELECTED");
            }
        });
```

I can see the entire list, but once I click on an item, nothing happans, and it wont show the selection at all, even if I use `setSelection()`, and if I try to do `spinnerCategories.getSelectedItem().toString()` I get a `NullPointerException`.
I tried searching the web a lot, but none solution seems to help me...

---

**Edit**

For some reason when I load the page and then I go out of the page and reenter it, only then it will show the selected items of the spinner

- On the first load it shows for a very brief second and then it's gone until the page is reentered the second time

Answer (score 1):

The setOnItemSelectedListener gets triggered when you click on an element from the drop down menu .. to fetch the selected item you need to use  `.getSelectedItemPosition()` something like
`categoriesList.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition)`

Comment: even with it, when I choose some option, the spinner will not show the selected, it jsut stays empty

Comment: get rid of the setOnItemSelectedListener unless you want something to happen the moment you select something from the spinner\

Comment: even without it, I still don't get to see the selection man...   it shows the dropdown but once I click on an item, it does not show it, it just keeps it a white blank box

Comment: do you have a solution?

Comment: Put a debugger in your categories list and see if it is populated.. don't see the error in your coc

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: Top right where you run there should be a bug like icon .. Now click on the sideline and put a breakpoint. Run thee bug like icon and then you can see the values in the respective elements